# Database Design Advice For Fees and Payments

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

Below is the current design of school fees and payment I have created. 
I'm just a little stuck right now because I can't model the payment/transaction table. Also, I would like to know your thoughts and comments with my current design. This is the first time I'll create a database for fees and payments.

[image]

Main tables of my concern are `schoolyearfee_lt` , `student_fee_lt` and `Payment`

I'm thinking of using the `Payment` table to store the sum of all fees on which will be divided to whatever payment term was chosen (monthly,quarterly,annual,cash).

Let's say for instance, Monthly was chosen as payment plan.

```
amountToPayPerMonth = (sumOfAllAssignedFees / paymentterm) - downpayment
```

Where 11 inserts of the `amountToPayPerMonth` to `payment` table will be executed and 1 `downpayment`. 11+1 = 12 months

How do I mark it as paid? Should I use another **Transaction** table?

Is this a good design? Any thoughts or advice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

some (personal) thoughts about your design and question.

1- **schoolyearfee_lt**. It seems 1-to-n with fee_mt. If i well understand the same fee can be applied for several shoolyears, category etc, but the amount for a fee does not change. It means, for example, that every year in which fee amounts change i should create -at least- a new fee and some shoolyearfee.  I believe something can be reviewed here. I could from example move some of its fields (schoolyear?) to the fee_mt table, and/or i could move the amount from fee_mt to schoolyearfee_lt. There are also some more possibilities, i.e. making a table fee_years_lt, where storing year and amount (and maybe other factors which change the fees) and so on. Maybe you could make some of these changes, maybe none, depends on your design and requirements.  The questions may be: is the amount changing by year (i believe yes), gradelevel, feetype, feecategory or not ? You want a master fee that you want applicable forever or your fees are recreated each year from scratch ?

2- **Payment**. I would call it exactly with its meaning: payment_plan. I would add a field paid, a field payment_date and a field schoolyear (in current design).

3- **Student_fee_lt and schoolyear**. In the current design you better add the year too. Depending on the mode the fee_mt is managed (see above) i would put it in the PK too. Moving the year to the fee_mt, you don't need. Is student_fee_lt really needed (it seems the result of a query + the field date_effective) ?

4- **Payment Formula**. The downpayment and consequently the formula is a little nclear to me. Is it a kind of discount for every payment you do or is it a fixed amount ? In the latter you should review your formula. Why 11 payments ?

5- **Choosen Payment Plan** storage. I would have a table where storing the chosen payment plan by the student (and some other data), this should not be student_fee_lt, because it stores the single fees assigned for each student.

Comment: First, thanks for taking the time to write such detailed answer. I need to create a Master table for all fees (Tuition,Lab,Library,etc) but I'm not sure where to put the amount field. Amounts of fee may/maynot change per schoolyear. New fees aside from Tuition,Lab,Library might be created as well.  Maybe my question really is on which table should I put a column that may/maynot change value? In this case, the amount of fee may/may not change per schoolyear but the names of fee(tuition,lab,etc) remain the same and new names of fees gets added. I hope it makes sense. Thank you.